# I want to find the word and replace the 3 word after the search string with my desired word in batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET InFile=test.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR "wordA" "%InFile%" ^| FINDSTR "wordB"') DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
pause
:FindString
SET String=%~1
SET String=%String:*wordA =%
SET String=%String: wordB=`%
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%A IN ('%String%') DO ECHO %%A
```

Here I just written a code to replace the word with my desired character
When I am running these code I am getting the error saying 
. was unexpected at this time

Comment: The first thing you need to do is put the command goto :eof between pause and :FindString because you are falling into the subroutine :FindString.  Beyond that can you explain... do you mean the really mean the "3rd word after the search string" or the 1st word after the search string.  An example of input and expected output would clarify.

Comment: suppose the string is getA=getb I would be searching for getA and letter after the getA would be replace by the word I give

Answer (score 1):

You were close.  See mods to your code below.  If you really want the first word after wordB... this will do it.
Don't enable delayed expansion if you don't need it because that just messes you up if there are ! in the text.

```
@echo off
SET InFile=test.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR "wordA" "%InFile%" ^| FINDSTR "wordB"') DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
pause
goto :eof

:FindString
SET String=%~1
SET String=%String:*wordA =%
SET String=%String:wordB =%
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN ('echo.%String%') DO ECHO.%%A
:goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you want, but you can try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
SET "InFile=test.txt"
echo(wordA wordB>"%InFile%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR "wordA" "%InFile%" ^| FINDSTR "wordB"') DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
pause
goto:eof

:FindString
SET "String=%~1"
SET "String=%String:*wordA =%"
SET "String=%String: wordB=`%"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%A IN ("%String%") DO ECHO %%A
```